# ClassCastException when using nested mappedBy with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, classcastexception

I have the following classes (simplified) :

## Location

Represents a geographic zone

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location extends DomainObject {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lastPositionHistoric.location")
    private Set<Thing> things = new LinkedHashSet<>(0);

    public Location() {
    }

    public Set<Thing> getThings(){
        return things;
    }

    public void setThings(Set<Thing> things){
        this.things = things;
    }

}
```

## Thing

Represents a moving asset

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thing")
public class Thing extends DomainObject {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_position_thing_historic_id")
    private ThingHistoric lastPositionHistoric;

    public Thing() {
    }

    public ThingHistoric getLastPositionHistoric() {
        return lastPositionHistoric;
    }

    public void setLastPositionHistoric(ThingHistoric lastPositionHistoric) {
        this.lastPositionHistoric = lastPositionHistoric;
    }

}
```

## ThingHistoric

Represents a GPS history of a Thing (I have removed unrelevant GPS properties for the problem)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thing_historic")
public class ThingHistoric extends DomainObject {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "thing_id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Thing thing;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    private Location location;

    public ThingHistoric() {

    }

    public Thing getThing() {
        return thing;
    }

    public ThingHistoric setThing(Thing thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
        return this;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public ThingHistoric setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
        return this;
    }
}
```

## Explanation

Each Thing moves in the real world and can be at a given time inside a location or in no location.

When a Thing is inside a location, the lastPositionHistoric object has its location value equal to the Location the thing is inside.

## The issue

When I added the **things** field inside the **Location** class, Hibernate started to complain with the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.ManyToOne cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Component
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getRecursiveProperty(PersistentClass.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getRecursiveProperty(PersistentClass.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:763)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 52 more
```

I don't understand why because the mapping seems correct to me.
The list of things inside a location should be all the things that have lastPositionHisotric.location equals to the given location, right ?

**Is it a bug or does my mapping is definitely wrong ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"." (dot) notation in `mappedBy` is to refer to fields within embedded attributes (see JPA spec 11.1.4.1 for example). It is not for use with entities! And I don't see anything embedded in your mappings. So yes your mapping is definitely wrong

> The dot (".") notation syntax must be used in the mappedBy element to
>   indicate the relationship attribute within the embedded attribute. The
>   value of each identifier used with the dot notation is the name of the
>   respective embedded field or property.

Comment: Oh I missed that point, thank for pointing that out ! Would there be another way to be able to map the list of Things from the Location ?

Comment: The only point of a mappedBy is to tie together 2 directly related fields to be bidirectional. With your current relations (without the mappedBy) you can still navigate between the different objects so don't see the problem

Comment: I can't navigate from location to things with this mapping. To solve it I added a copy of the current location id directly in the thing table. I mark your answer as accepted because it helped me re-think what I was doing.